# Twitter Bootstrap: Reload Current Tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How do you reload the currently selected Twitter Bootstrap tab?

This is what I have so far, but it just makes any subsequent tabs reload multiple times.

```
function reload_tab() {
   $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
       $('#tab-loaded-content').load($(e.target).attr('href'));
   });
}
```

Comment: I think you'd only need `$('#tab-loaded-content').load($('li.active a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('href'));` haven't tried it so let me know if it fails.

Comment: It works! Thanks! You should put your answer in the proper answer section to this question so that I can give you answer rep.

Comment: Great! I didn't want to do that before as I wasn't 100% confident with the answer but I've done that now. Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just

```
$('#tab-loaded-content').load($('li.active a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('href'));
```

What you were doing is every time you call the reload function, it binds to the `shown` event (didn't know that existed honestly) to reload that tab. Call it twice, tabs will reload twice. not what you want!

The one liner above simply tells it to load the content from the `href` attribute of the link that is a child of the active tab `li.active`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution from sachleen worked partialliy for me. First of all I had to replace tab-loaded-content with the actual tab to be updated:

```
$('#project_contracttaken').load($('li.active a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('href'));
```

But it still  did not update the content, I had to disable the jquery ajax cache functionality, for example:

```
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    cache: false
});
```

After these changes, it worked fine for me!