# reloading current active tab in twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was following [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388074/twitter-bootstrap-reload-current-tab) about how to be able to reload current active tab by using:

```
$('#tab-loaded-content').load($('li.active a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('href'));
```

But when I tried this the result was that it loads the initially active tab (the one defined in my html as active) and not the current active tab.
So I'm looking for some help to figure out how to do this.

Here is a simplified version of my issue:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
  <body>
    <div class="tabbable">      
      <ul id="mainTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tabWelcome" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabProject" data-toggle="tab">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabEmail" data-toggle="tab">Invite Friends</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabProfile" data-toggle="tab">My Profile</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tabWelcome">
          welcome
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tabProject">
          project
        <button id="button" class="btn">Create Project</button>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tabEmail">
        email
      </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tabProfile">
          profile
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
        $('#mainTabs').load($('li.active a[data-toggle="tab"]').attr('href'));
    }, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is when clicking on the "project" button on the second tab it should reload that tab, but it reloads the "welcome" tab.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to implement a very similar functionality.

Basically you need to get hold of the current tab 'deactivate' and show it again.

```
$(document).on('click', '#refresh', function () {
    var $link = $('li.active a[data-toggle="tab"]');
    $link.parent().removeClass('active');
    var tabLink = $link.attr('href');
    $('#mainTabs a[href="' + tabLink + '"]').tab('show');
});
```

See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ceokot/RqmKw/6/) for a working demo.

Notice the demo is using Bootstrap 3 hence the use of the `shown.bs.tab` event to show the time at tab load.

Comment: In the purpose of improvement : you can lose the 'var tablink' and "$('#mainTabs...)"  replacing the latter by $link.tab('show')